# How to use tomcat authentication whenever a page reloads

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications

I have been developing a web app consisting of a login page and users database maintenance and i am using tomcat authentication to verify users credentials. I have configured the tomcat in such a way that when the url of certain servlet is called the authentication  pops up. But i can use that authentication only once and after logging in if i come back to the same page there is no authentication from the server.

[image: this is the code i have used to call the authenticator]

Comment: Please don't post code in an image.

Comment: It's just how basic authentication works. You can delete the stored credentials in you browser, that's about it.

Comment: any idea of how to do that?

Comment: I'm afraid it must be done manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah i found the answer. Just include the Session.Invalidate() code in your corresponding sign out page and it terminates the session. But you have to change the authentication from to FORM.